# $\int_0^k \sin(tx-mod(\frac{\pi}{2}(t-1),2\pi))dt$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, modular-arithmetic

I've been investigating series of  sine and cosine, and I came across the funky-looking function $I(x)$ for real $x$ and non-negative (constant) $k$.
$$I(x)=\int_0^k \sin(tx-mod(\frac{\pi}{2}(t-1),2\pi))dt$$
Can someone help me compute this gross integral?

Comment: Since $\sin$ is periodic $2\pi$ you can remove the $\mod 2\pi$ in the integrand. So you are left with $\int_0^k \sin(tx - \frac{\pi}{2}(t-1)){\rm d}t$ which is easy.

Comment: @Winther oh wow I didn't realize that. Thanks!

Comment: btw what is $\text{mod}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(t-1), 2\pi\right)$?? I mean as we know that $a \equiv b(\mod n)$ means $(a=kn+b$ like that